# Is there a limit for the byte size on a response Body using retrofit?

Tags: android, sockets, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I wanted to know if the byte size of a Json Response body can cause an issue using a retrofit.

Right now I am having a kind of random issue with a callback using retrofit with the default OkHttp Client, Everything shows as okay on the Http Interceptor Logs but in code, it takes the call as a Failure and throws a simple message

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout detail message: timeout

or

Socket Closed. java.net.SocketException

NO more, no less.
Those issues have been dead ends for me, as they have not shown me a possible solution to my issue, and most likely point me in the wrong direction.

Now the only lead I have is that the byte size of that Jason is (276837-byte body)
when most of my other response bodies don't go over 512 bytes, It makes me believe that there may be a default OkHttpCLient or Retrofit build have a limitation that I am not aware of.

The issue is random even a development environment but if I switch the network type to HSDPA or anything different from LTA or Full it gives me a socket closed or timeout error, while on Full it only happens sometimes.

I am going to put my code to see if is of any help.

This is my Gradle implementation

---

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
```

This is how I build my Client and retrofit

---

```
private fun buildRetrofit(): Retrofit {

    val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val client = OkHttpClient()
        .newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(logger)
        .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(FN.returnWebAPI(this))
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

}
```

This is how I make the call, now is just receiving a response body to be sure it doesn't have to do with the parsing of the data.

---

```
val idGrupoComercios = hashMapOf("idGrupo" to id)
                val hashComercio = HashComercio(hash, upperU.usuario.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()), "", jwt.toString(), idGrupoComercios
                )
            val callComercios: Call<ResponseBody> =
                service.getComercios(tokenBearer, hashComercio)

            callComercios.enqueue(object :
                Callback<ResponseBody> {
                override fun onFailure(
                    call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                    t: Throwable
                ) {
                    Crashlytics.logException(t)

                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                    response: Response<ResponseBody>
                ) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                       val data = response.body()!!

                }

            })
```

Also, some other information that may help
The configuration of my emulator
Default LTE (The error - socket closed or timeout appears randomly)
[image]

--Options given by the android emulator 
(Full and LTE error appears randomly, any other one , always show a timeout or socket closed exception)
[image]

---The one that always gives issues
[image]

------My HtttLogger Interceptor

> ```
> D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 D/OkHttp:
> ```
>
> Content-Length: 418 D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiJCRFo1R0EiLCJqdGkiOiI0NmI0MTA0NC03M2M2LTQ5MDEtOTcyMy0yZjE1NjE1ODgzZDgiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAzMjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.EgVFlAzqOlV-RpjRRxXpQzp3q3kk1FqTcoaGDQBY0XA
>
> ```
> D/OkHttp: {"anyObjects":{"idGrupo":"00d60025-6fb9-484f-97f0-08d79dfdbf92"},"cultura":"","hash":"BDZ5GA","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiJCRFo1R0EiLCJqdGkiOiI0NmI0MTA0NC03M2M2LTQ5MDEtOTcyMy0yZjE1NjE1ODgzZDgiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAzMjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.EgVFlAzqOlV-RpjRRxXpQzp3q3kk1FqTcoaGDQBY0XA","usuario":"USER_BONANZA1"}
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (418-byte body)
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios (34ms)
>
> D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> D/OkHttp: Server: Kestrel
>
> D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 01:05:45 GMT
> ```

I hope this is of any help if you could give me any advice it will be taken, also if someone could tell me how to see the inner workings of the client and how can I see error more precisely I would really appreciate it. 
I want more info and this issue seems to not be clear, I believe that something can be done from the application side.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.
If there is an issue with the Response Body Byte size Retrofit would tell you about it.
But for 3g networks and some, you may have an issue with a retrofit if your response body is over 1024 bytes or contains has values that may increase the time retrofit takes to reconstruct the response.